# Jupyter Notebook: Run cell/select below, how to default to edit mode?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook the shortcut for run cell/select below is Shift+Return. The issue I have is that it selects the below cell in Command mode and not Edit mode, therefore requiring an extra step each time to go into Edit Mode.

Question: How can I change that, and is that a possibility?

Here are some images to make it a bit more clear in case I wasn't. Nevermind apparently need more Reputation before I can embed pictures, Sorry for the inconvenience.

[Before Run cell/Select Below (Shift+Return)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHea3.png)

[After Run cell/Select Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3sI9.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBfes.png)

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you're looking for the **'Run cell and insert new cell below'**

You need Alt+Enter for that
https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/iPython_Notebook.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index

If it is inconvenient to use, you can try changing the shortcuts.

Follow: 
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html